# Kafka commit strategies in MassTransit

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, masstransit

There are three Kafka connector commit strategies that we can choose based on different scenarios:

- throttled
- latest
- ignore

and currently I need to know how should I configure those if I want use Kafka in `MassTransit` Rider!

the ignore strategy should be the most straightforward one to just set `EnableAutoOffsetStore = true` in `TopicEndpoint` config action.

I need to know how should it be configured/implemented to have `latest` strategy as well as `throttled`!

Any idea/clue is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MassTransit automatically manages the checkpoint behavior when consuming messages from topics, the only values to configure (if desired) are the checkpoint interval and message limits.

`CheckpointInterval`

`CheckpointMessageCount`

Comment: if any exception throws in `IConsumer` -> `Consume` it wouldn't be committed?

Comment: and how's the best way to retry on failure consumptions? thanks @Chris

Comment: `UseMessageRetry`, and configure it to be a really high retry count. But the scope of how to retry messages when Kafka consumers experience exceptions are beyond the scope of this comment.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson
Is there any way to manually control the commit in case of restart, exception, etc?